# Combine year specific MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a separate database for every competition year and I know I can combine the majority of the tables between databases by simply adding a year field. However, in each database there are 2 tables that can vary dramatically from year to year: `matches` and `stats`.

In the match table, the number of team fields can vary from 4-6, scoring fields from 1-4 and other fields depending on how scoring data is tabulated. And in the statistics table, the same scoring data is tabulated on a per team basis to allow for event rankings.

I guess my question is would it be better for me to combine, storing the varying data fields as one in a serialized array and use PHP's `array_multisort()` to get the data in order, or leave it as is, or do something else?

Comment: I don't get your question, but I can tell you that for MySQL it's almost no difference if the tables are in one database or in different.

Comment: If I'm going to combine the tables into one database, I only want to have one set of tables. I want to know if I should merge all the tables named `matches` into one table and likewise with all the `stats` tables.

Comment: From gut feeling I'd say, if the merged tables will have more than, say, 10 000 000 lines in the near future, leave them separate.

Comment: That's hopefully decades out. :-) My other concern is how PHP will handle it, load times and all, as stats changes based on match data and caching isn't really an option during the competition season.

Comment: You will find out during testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the tables is the logical choice, given you don't have an enormously large amount of records (as AndreKR said). Sorting using `array_multisort()` works like a charm. Just keep in mind if you aren't sorting on the same fields every time, you'll want to call the function using `call_user_func_array()` which can be a little tricky if you haven't used it before. I had to do this to achieve the intended order of display for my data.